# how to uninstall maridb and install remysql in centos 7 , linux?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have installed maria db in my centos 7 , But now after uninstalling the maridb with:

```
yum remove MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

when I install the  mysql-devel or mysql or mysql-server it always install maridb. 
 How can I move back to mysql?
I have also removed the mariadb respository from the list of repositories at:/etc/yum.repos.d 
On:

```
yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel
```

Error log on the cmd:

```
[root@ONS88 ~]# yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.s.uw.edu
 * epel: fedora.mirrors.pair.com
 * extras: centos.s.uw.edu
 * ius: mirror.its.dal.ca
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: centos.s.uw.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb101u.x86_64 1:10.1.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb101u-common(x86-64) = 1:10.1.29-1.ius.centos7 for package: 1:mariadb101u-10.1.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb101u-libs(x86-64) = 1:10.1.29-1.ius.centos7 for package: 1:mariadb101u-10.1.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
---> Package mariadb101u-devel.x86_64 1:10.1.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.38-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.38-2.el7 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.38-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 5.6.10 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.38-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb101u-common.x86_64 1:10.1.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb101u-config(x86-64) = 1:10.1.29-1.ius.centos7 for package: 1:mariadb101u-common-10.1.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
---> Package mariadb101u-libs.x86_64 1:10.1.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.38-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 5.6.10 for package: mysql-community-client-5.6.38-2.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.38-2.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb101u-config.x86_64 1:10.1.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.38-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: 1:mariadb101u-libs-10.1.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts mysql-community-libs
--> Processing Conflict: 1:mariadb101u-10.1.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts mysql-community-client
--> Processing Conflict: 1:mariadb101u-config-10.1.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts mysql-community-server
--> Processing Conflict: 1:mariadb101u-common-10.1.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts mysql-community-common
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mariadb101u-libs conflicts with mysql-community-libs-5.6.38-2.el7.x86_64
Error: mariadb101u conflicts with mysql-community-client-5.6.38-2.el7.x86_64
Error: mariadb101u-config conflicts with mysql-community-server-5.6.38-2.el7.x86_64
Error: mariadb101u-common conflicts with mysql-community-common-5.6.38-2.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 115 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
ModemManager-1.6.0-2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with ModemManager-1.1.0-8.git20130913.el7.x86_64
ModemManager-glib-1.6.0-2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with ModemManager-glib-1.1.0-8.git20130913.el7.x86_64
adcli-0.8.1-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with adcli-0.7.5-4.el7.x86_64
alsa-tools-firmware-1.1.0-1.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with alsa-tools-firmware-1.0.28-2.el7.x86_64
at-3.1.13-22.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with at-3.1.13-20.el7.x86_64
avahi-0.6.31-17.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with avahi-0.6.31-15.el7.x86_64
avahi-autoipd-0.6.31-15.el7.x86_64 has installed conflicts avahi > ('0', '0.6.31', '15.el7'): avahi-0.6.31-17.el7.x86_64
avahi-autoipd-0.6.31-17.el7.x86_64 has installed conflicts avahi < ('0', '0.6.31', '17.el7'): avahi-0.6.31-15.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Once Read this  https://features.cpanel.net/topic/returning-back-to-mysql-after-upgrade-to-mariadb-via-cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sudo yum install http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm

$ sudo yum repolist enabled | grep "mysql.*-community.*"
    
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
 
$ sudo systemctl status mysqld
```

Login in to mysql

```
 $ mysql -u root
```

Mysql auto-start on boot

```
  $ sudo systemctl enable mysqld.service
```

link to the complete answer https://dbahire.com/how-to-install-mysql-5-6-on-centos-7/

To set the password while using mysql

## mysql_secure_installation